# Input type number is not working in firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I have an issue.I have an input field which type is `number` but its taking any alphabet in mozila firefox browser.Its working great in chrome but not working in firefox.I need it should work as chrome and not take any alphabet.I am using Mozila firefox version 48.0.I am explaining my code below.

```
<input type="number"  class="form-control oditek-form"  ng-model="type" name="type" step="1" min="0" placeholder="Add Type">
```

Please help me.

Comment: For Firefox- without javascript it is not possible. Still the field is working,  if u wrong and type any non digit symbol -  field it is not validated in that case. 
If you need example, how to do that with JS, let me know.

Comment: Firefox 39 in Mac OSX by default does not prevent alpha characters input and Firefox 42 validates only but It doesn't disable alpha keys input.
Referred from : http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number (Known issues Tab)

Answer (score 1):

i am using firefox too, i had the same issue developing my input type number typing caracters and spaces etc...
i have found the solution of the tag pattern="[1-9]", but unfortunately it didn't work for me. After a wile of searching without any result, i decided to develop my own function.
anyway i m using angular 2 in this examples, its almost similar to javascript, so you can use this code in every case :
here is the html :

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="qte" type="number"  min="1" max="30" step="1" [(ngModel)]="numberVoucher"
     (keypress)="FilterInput($event)" />
```

here is the function FilterInput :

```
FilterInput(event: any) {
        let numberEntered = false;
        if ((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) || (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40)) { //input number entered or one of the 4 directtion up, down, left and right
            //console.log('input number entered :' + event.which + ' ' + event.keyCode + ' ' + event.charCode);
            numberEntered = true;
        }
        else {
            //input command entered of delete, backspace or one of the 4 directtion up, down, left and right
            if ((event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40) || event.keyCode == 46 || event.which == 8) {
                //console.log('input command entered :' + event.which + ' ' + event.keyCode + ' ' + event.charCode);
            }
            else {
                //console.log('input not number entered :' + event.which + ' ' + event.keyCode + ' ' + event.charCode);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        // input is not impty
        if (this.validForm) {
            // a number was typed
            if (numberEntered) {
                let newNumber = parseInt(this.numberVoucher + '' + String.fromCharCode(event.which));
                console.log('new number : ' + newNumber);
                // checking the condition of max value
                if ((newNumber <= 30 && newNumber >= 1) || Number.isNaN(newNumber)) {
                    console.log('valid number : ' + newNumber);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('max value will not be valid');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            // command of delete or backspace was types
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.which == 8) {
                if (this.numberVoucher >= 1 && this.numberVoucher <= 9) {
                    console.log('min value will not be valid');
                    this.numberVoucher = 1;
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    this.validForm = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // input is empty
        else {
            console.log('this.validForm = true');
            this.validForm = false;
        }
    };
```

in this function i had to just let the keypress of numbers, direction, deletes enter.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The min attribute of the tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Firefox.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp